# Find Probability Density Function of $Y = X^3$, where $X$ is an exponential distribution of parameter $4$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, exponential-distribution

Random variable $X$ is an exponential distribution of parameter $4$.

I have another random variable, $Y = X^3$. I need to find probability density function of Y, $f_y(y)$.

Here's what I did:
$$F_y(y) = P(Y < y) = P(X^3 < y) = F_y(x^3)$$

now, I took the derivative [I've used the chain rule], $$3\cdot x^2f_y(x^3)$$

does it make sense?

Comment: $P(X^3 < y) = P(X < y^{1/3}) = F_X(y^{1/3})$

Comment: The step $P(X^3 < y) = F_Y(X^3)$ is not correct. You want to get an expression of the form $P(X < z) = F_X(z)$ for some $z$, where $F_X$ is the distribution function of $X$, your  exponentially distributed random variable.

Comment: What is "an exponential distribution with parameter 4"? That is, what is the formula for its cumulative, its density?

Comment: I don't need $f_x(z)$, but I need $f_y(z)$ instead

Comment: $f_x(z)$ is the exponential density function, but I need the density function of Y.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei what you wrote can be used to find $f_y(y)$?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini just use the chain rule to correct CDF of $Y$ as you did to the incorrect one

Comment: @Yalikesifulei but it's not $F_y(z)$, if I use the chain rule on $F_x(z)$, then I find the probability density function of x, not y.

Answer (score 1):

> Here's what I did:  $$F_y(y) = P(Y < y) = P(X^3 < y) = F_y(x^3)$$

The last step is clearly invalid.  From where did the free variable $x$ come ?  Just substituting $y=x^3$ is of no help.

The subscripts may indicate your confusion. The letters $Y$ and $y$ do not mean the same thing.  $Y$ is a random variable, while $y$ is a value; likewise $X$ and $x$.  The subscripts should be capitals, showing that they are the CDF for *the Random Variables*, like so: $F_Y(\cdot)$ and $F_X(\cdot)$ .

You do not want an expression in $x$ involving the function $F_Y(\cdot)$.  Rather, you want an expression in $y$ involving the function $F_X(\cdot)$ .

So you should have:

$$\begin{align} F_{\small Y}(y) &= P(Y \leqslant y) \\&= P(X^3 \leqslant y)\\&= P(X\leqslant y^{1/3}) \\&= F_{\small X}(y^{1/3})\end{align}$$

And since $X\sim\mathcal{Exp}(4)$ then $F_{\small Y}(y) = (1-\mathrm e^{-4 y^{1/3}})\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y}$

> now, I took the derivative [I've used the chain rule],

That is the correct move, just from the wrong place.  Apply it to:

$$f_{\small Y}(y)= \dfrac {\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm d y}F_{\small X}(y^{1/3})$$